# jQuery (or something) is not working properly on IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8

#### UPDATE:

> I was told to test this in IE9 - It works fine in IE9 (for me,
>   anyways).

I was told by a friend that [THIS](http://nanisolutions.us/wordpress/mitzvah/) page is not running properly on IE8 - I was told that the thumbnails are loading properly, but the image in the center is not. I do not have IE8 and I have been unsuccessful in my attempt to download it.

The images are being loaded (well, adjusted) through jQuery and I have a feeling that it is my javascript code that is failing in some way, causing the described errors in IE8.

I put my code through JSLint and the errors I saw were telling me to add spaces in the code - but I highly doubt this could be causing the IE8 issue.

The JS file being loaded is "slideshow.js" which can be easily found through Chrome's inspect element.

I will keep inspecting this from my end looking for JS errors and what not but I would really appreciate some help on this issue.

Thank you very much,

Evan

Comment: Do you have IE9? If you do you have IE8. Or you are not a MS user :)

Comment: I do have IE9. They are the same thing? How can I use IE8 over IE9?

Comment: F12 to open up the developer console. On the top you can change the rendering engine. Make sure to change both options to IE8.

Comment: What happens if you toggle Compatibility mode in IE8 ? I'm on a mac so I can't try this myself.

Comment: I've confirmed, it's not working in IE8 - I think "natural width" is not supported.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that IE8 does not support the "naturalWidth" property. Rather, one should create a new image object, and get the "width" from this new image object.

For more details, refer to this [link..](http://jacklmoore.com/notes/naturalwidth-and-naturalheight-in-ie)

Answer (score 0):

Problem looks to be

`.img-wrapper`  in style.css with `position:absolute`.

Comment: what is the problem with using absolute positioned elements in IE8? I didn't find anything when reading.

Comment: Nothing is, but something with your code is causing the problem. Removing the rule in IE8 and it worked.

Comment: I found the problem - naturalwidth and naturalHeight is not supported in IE8

http://www.jacklmoore.com/notes/naturalwidth-and-naturalheight-in-ie