# jquery not working properly in internet explorer

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

The following jQuery function gives me the error message "Broken image!" only in Internet Explorer 8. It works fine in Chrome, Firefox. Any ideas?

```
function displayPortrait()
{
   $('#big_picture').html('<img src="css/img/loading_img.gif" style="margin-top: 200px;  margin-left:250px;" />');
   var img = $("<img />").attr('src', 'css/img/portrait.jpg').attr('style', 'margin-left:100px;margin-top:0px;').load(function() {
     if (!this.complete || typeof this.naturalWidth == "undefined" || this.naturalWidth == 0) {
         alert('broken image!');
     } else {
         $("#big_picture").html(img);
     }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

See this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10238771/1012381): `naturalWidth` and `naturalHeight` are not supported in IE 8.